# SQL filter LEFT TABLE before left join

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have read a number of posts from SO and I understand the differences between filtering in the where clause and on clause. But most of those examples are filtering on the RIGHT table (when using left join). If I have a query such as below:

```
select * from tableA A left join tableB B on A.ID = B.ID and A.ID = 20
```

The return values are not what I expected. I would have thought it first filters the left table and fetches only rows with ID = 20 and then do a left join with tableB.

Of course, this should be technically the same as doing:

```
select * from tableA A left join table B on A.ID = B.ID where A.ID = 20
```

But I thought the performance would be better if you could filter the table before doing a join. Can someone enlighten me on how this SQL is processed and help me understand this thoroughly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `left join` follows a simple rule.  It keeps all the rows in the first table.  The *values* of columns depend on the `on` clause.  If there is no match, then the corresponding table's columns are `NULL` -- whether the first or second table.

So, for this query:

```
select *
from tableA A left join
     tableB B
     on A.ID = B.ID and A.ID = 20;
```

All the rows in `A` are in the result set, regardless of whether or not there is a match.  When the id is not 20, then the rows and columns are still taken from `A`.  However, the condition is false so the columns in `B` are `NULL`.  This is a simple rule.  It does not depend on whether the conditions are on the first table or the second table.

For this query:

```
select *
from tableA A left join
     tableB B
     on A.ID = B.ID 
where A.ID = 20;
```

The `from` clause keeps all the rows in `A`.  But then the `where` clause has its effect.  And it filters the rows so on only id 20s are in the result set.

When using a `left join`:

- Filter conditions on the first table go in the `where` clause.
- Filter conditions on subsequent tables go in the `on` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but could you elaborate on this "When the id is not 20, then the column values are NULL". Do you mean the ID of tableB is not 20, then all the columns from tableB will be null? And is there a use case for this? Or should the filtering on first table always go to where clause?

Comment: @TFK . . . I fixed the phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have from tablea, you could put a subquery like from  (select x.* from tablea X where x.value=20) TA

Then refer to TA like you did tablea previously.

Likely the query optimizer would do this for you.

Oracle should have a way to show the query plan. Put "Explain plan" before the sql statement. Look at the plan both ways and see what it does.

Comment: You are logically correct, but the optimizer does not re-write it that way; it hs an OUTER JOIN operator.

Answer (score 0):

In your first SQL statement, `A.ID=20` is not being joined to anything technically.  Joins are used to connect two separate tables together, with the `ON` statement joining columns by associating them as keys.

`WHERE` statements allow the filtering of data by reducing the number of rows returned only where that value can be found under that particular column.